# Programmatically getting a list of all apps in an android device

Tags: android

How do I get a list of all apps in an android device,which includes the system apps,and the uninstalled apps in storage.

Answer (score 0):

> You can easily get all Applications installed on a device using this code :

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

> The `pkgAppsList` has all the Apps which includes system and user apps

Comment: What about uninstalled apps in phone storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out different methods as suggested in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-get-list-of-all-apps-installed-in-your-android-phone/)

```
List<ApplicationInfo> infos = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
// create a list with sze of total number of apps 
String[] apps = new String[infos.size()];
int i = 0;
// add all the app name in string list
for (ApplicationInfo info : infos) {
    apps[i] = info.packageName;
    i++;
}
```